# AWS Batch: cancel job not working for jobs in RUNNABLE state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

### Summary

I am using AWS Batch in order to run Monte Carlo simulations. Occasionally I realise that a group of jobs that I have submitted to my queue are incorrect in some way and I wish to clean up the queue before more jobs start running.

When I try the to cancel the job through the AWS Console I get a the notification ["Job cancellation request completed successfully"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjipP.png). However, the job remains in the queue, even after waiting for multiple hours. I don't know how to cancel these jobs.

### What I've tried

- Cancelling jobs in the `RUNNABLE` through the AWS Console manually. I get a "Job cancellation request completed successfully", but no change.
- Terminating jobs in the `RUNNABLE` through the AWS Console manually, instead of cancelling. No change either.
- Cancelling jobs through the AWS CLI with `aws batch cancel-job` command as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/batch/cancel-job.html
- Terminating jobs through the AWS CLI with `aws batch terminate-job` command as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/batch/terminate-job.html

For all of the previous cases, the job remained in the queue afterwards, with the same status (`RUNNABLE`).

Answer (score 0):

This is normal: "Terminates a job in a job queue. Jobs that are in the STARTING or RUNNING state are terminated, which causes them to transition to FAILED . Jobs that have not progressed to the STARTING state are cancelled." from the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/batch/terminate-job.html.